# MVC routes with dynamic values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, url-routing

I am struggling with the MVC routes
I want to get the following URLs;

1. example.com/sector/
2. example.com/sector/ddmmyyy/
3. example.com/sector/ddmmyyy/article-with-seo-url/

All 3 values are dynamic (Sector / Date / SEOURL).

I can get No.1 (/sectors/) working with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "sectors",
  "{seourl}",
  new { controller = "NewsArticle", action = "sectors" }
);
```

However I'm not sure how to get the routes for the other 2 dynamic values.

Thanks

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to specify default values for `Date` and `SEOURL`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "sectors",
   "{sectorName}/{date}/{seourl}",
   new { constroller = "NewsArticle", action = "sectors",
         date = 0, seourl = string.Empty },
   new { date = "\d+" });
```

If you go to `http://www.example.com/apple`, then:

- sectorName = ***apple***
- date = ***0***
- seourl = ***""*** (Empty string)

If you go to `http://www.example.com/apple/240514`, then:

- sectorName = ***apple***
- date = ***240514***
- seourl = ***""*** (Empty string)

Your `sectors` action, should probably have the following signature:

```
public ActionResult sectors(string sectorName, int date, string seourl)
```

And (just in case), I would assign default values to the action's parameters too:

```
public ActionResult sectors(string sectorName, int date = 0, string seourl = string.Empty);
```

Comment: Would make processing easier to have date as a string in the action method.

Comment: @buffjape If it's an integer it would be easier to validate by the route handler.